# Doctrine 2 WHERE IN clause using a collection of entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm attempting to build a query in Doctrine 2 that finds all `Vacancy` entities which are related to any of the given `VacancyWorkingHours` entities.

The `Vacancy` entity looks as follows:

```
/**
 * Vacancy
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vacancy")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JaikDean\CareersBundle\Entity\VacancyRepository")
 */
class Vacancy
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var VacancyWorkingHours
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VacancyWorkingHours", inversedBy="vacancies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vacancy_working_hours_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $workingHours;

    /* Other fields and methods are inconsequential */
}
```

My query currently looks as follows, but returns no results because of the where clause. In this example, `$workingHours` is a `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` instance containing a number of `VacancyWorkingHours` entities

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('v')
    ->andWhere('v.workingHours IN (:workingHours)')
    ->setParameter('workingHours', $workingHours->toArray());
;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A [pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/590) I made about this has been merged into Doctrine ORM 2.5, so you can simply do this now:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('v')
    ->andWhere('v.workingHours IN (:workingHours)')
    ->setParameter('workingHours', $workingHours);
;
```

The latest version of Doctrine now allows collection parameters and will automatically make use of the primary key of each of the collection entries.

Answer (score 17):

Try to set IDs as parameter

```
$ids = array();
foreach($workingHours as $w) {
    $ids[] = $w->getId();
}
```

Then

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('v')
    ->andWhere('v.workingHours IN (:workingHours)')
    ->setParameter('workingHours', $ids);
;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It seems strange/wrong to have to reference the key field though rather than letting Doctrine handle it.

Comment: @JaikDean Yes indeed that's weird, and that's why I proposed a patch to enhance this so that it works with entities rather than ids. It has been merged and will be available in Doctrine 2.5 : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/590

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin Good news!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using DQL in this way:

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('v.workingHours', $ids));
;
```

And let Doctrine handle the expression & quotation work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the DQL will work better for that.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT v
    FROM YourAppYourBundle:YourEntity v // exemple AcmeexampleBundle:YourEntity
    WHERE v.workingHours IN :workingHours'
)->setParameter('workingHours', $workingHours->toArray());

$vacancies = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks, I might end up going down that route. The particular WHERE IN clause is actually part of a bigger query which is being built up based on various other conditions, so using the query builder is easier from an organisational point of view.