# Query Builder where IN arrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How is it possible to get that query return results ?
productCategory is arrayCollection of objects that are related to formItemPosition.

```
        $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder('fi');
        $items = $qb
                ->innerJoin('fi.formItemPosition', 'fip')
                ->where('fip.productCategory IN (:productCategories)')
                ->andWhere('fip.documentCategory = :documentCategory')
                ->setParameters(['documentCategory' => $documentCategory,
                    'productCategories' => $productCategories
            ]);
```

Comment: I quickly glanced over and I saw nothing wrong. What is the issue here?

Comment: returns null all the time, but it should return 36 rows, in sql it looks like : 
SELECT * 
FROM owca.formgenerator_item as fi 
INNER JOIN owca.formgenerator_itemposition as fip ON fi.id = fip.formItem_id
WHERE fip.productCategory_id IN (20,50,100000)
AND fip.documentCategory_id = 1;

Comment: Do you execute the query, via a `$qb->getQuery->getResult()` ?

Comment: And if you did, what does `$qb->getQuery()->getSql()` returns ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 WHERE IN clause using a collection of entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536190/doctrine-2-where-in-clause-using-a-collection-of-entities)