# Check if an array contains any element of another array in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.1

I would like to know if it's possible to check if an array contains any element of another array in doctrine query builder.

In my case, i want to get all the products (items) who have at least one of the category in the array passed in parameter.

> Relationship between Item and Category :

```
/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
 *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="items_categories",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
 *      )
 */
private $categories;
```

> My first try from the Item repository (i know this work if i have only
>   one value to check):

```
public function getListItemsFromCatList($listCat) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');

    $qb->select('i')
            ->where($qb->expr()->like('i.categories', ':listCat'))
            ->setParameter('listCat', '%"' . $listCat . '"%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**$listCat is an array of Category Entity :**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(ItemBundle\Entity\Category)[518]
      private 'id' => int 22
      private 'children' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[520]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(ItemBundle\Entity\Category)[518]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[796]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'parent' (length=6)
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[579]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean false
          protected 'collection' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[515]
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean true
      private 'parent' => null
      private 'name' => string 'Luxe' (length=4)
  1 => 
    object(ItemBundle\Entity\Category)[504]
      private 'id' => int 25
      private 'children' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[505]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(ItemBundle\Entity\Category)[504]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[796]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'parent' (length=6)
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[579]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean false
          protected 'collection' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[500]
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean false
      private 'parent' => 
        object(ItemBundle\Entity\Category)[512]
          private 'id' => int 23
          private 'children' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[513]
              ...
          private 'parent' => 
            object(ItemBundle\Entity\Category)[518]
              ...
          private 'name' => string 'Bijoux' (length=6)
      private 'name' => string 'Bagues' (length=6)
```

Comment: See my edit #2 which I think might work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would solve it adding a join.

```
public function getListItemsFromCatList($listCat) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('i')           
        ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
        ->innerJoin('i.categories','cat')
        ->where('cat IN (:listCat)')
       ->setParameter('listCat', $listCat);

    return  = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Notice this approach will filter the categories inside items. It means that when you try to get categories from a given item `i`, `$i->getCategories()`, it will return only the categories from `i` which matchs with `$listCat`.

If you will need to use all categories from each item, even those doesn't match with `$listCat`. I will recommend you to use subqueries to filter, and main query to return the full items. Let a comment if you need any futher help with that.

Comment: In my case just have the category which match with `$listCat` is OK. So Thank you for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Try your query builder like this instead:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('i')
    ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
    ->where('i.categories LIKE :listCat')
    ->setParameter('listCat', '%"' . $listCat . '"%');

return  = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I think that should work. I'm presuming the Entity in Doctrine you are using is called `Item`.

**EDIT #2 - based on comments**

You need to loop through the array and get the name (I think), which I think is the category you are looking for. In this code I show looping through to create a `$cats` variable, and then use that in a `IN` query.

```
foreach ($listCat as $item){
    $cats = $cats . "'" . $item.getName() . "'".',';
}
$cats = substr($cats, -1);


$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('i')
    ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
    ->where("i.categories IN (:listCat)")
    ->setParameter('listCat', $cats);

return  = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Can you try it? I think you need something like that.

Comment: This is the same as my test. For information, $listcat is an array of Category Entity. So this can't Work ( i just tried and i get the following error : Notice: Array to string conversion)

Comment: Is `$listCat` an array?

Comment: Please show an example of what `$listCat` contains. Maybe you can use `IN` instead?

Comment: Done, but i don't think this will work because `i.categories` is a collection too. What would be great, would to have the behavior on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php)

Comment: I get this error : `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 47 near 'categories IN': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

I think it's normal  because the IN clause is waiting for only one value on left side (i.categories)

Comment: As long as `$cats` contains a proper format it should work. I edited to include single quotes around the strings. Also, I see [you can directly use an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536190/doctrine-2-where-in-clause-using-a-collection-of-entities). My answer should work regardless. Please take the time to troubleshoot before posting further comments.

Comment: Thank you for helping but as i say before i still have the same error and it seems logical

Comment: I just did a [check for that error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666692/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression-in-query-builder-wi), and I think you need to add `IDENTITY(i.id)` or whatever composite key. You might want to investigate this. Sorry i couldn't help more.